# Animating subplots mixing matrices and line plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I am writing a project in python that includes animation with matplotlib. The thing is I have to visualize a window divided into two rows and two columns, so 4 subplots. In `ax[0,0]`, `ax[0,1]` and `ax[1,0]` I have matrices. In `ax[1][1]` a 2D line plot.
The animation of the subplots with the matrices are working properly, but the line one does not.

The error is:

```py
list object has no attribute set_data
```

The code is really long, so I will do a schematization. Could you please tell me what I did wrong?

```py
rows, cols = 2, 3
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=rows, ncols=cols, num=None, figsize=(16, 12), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

# Initialization of matrices MATR1, MATR2, MATR3 all cells set to 0 #

# Coordinates lists for the line plot
x_time = []
y_values = []

index = count()

im = list()
im.append(ax[0][0].imshow(MATR1, cmap='Reds', animated=True))
im.append(ax[0][1].imshow(MATR2, cmap='Greens', animated=True))
im.append(ax[1][0].imshow(MATR3, animated=True))
im.append(ax[1][1].plot(x_time, y_values, animated=True))

def animate(i):
    ax[1][1].cla()
    
    # Here a lot of code that determines the values that are inserted into the matrices and the value
    # to add in the y_values coordinates list for the line #
    
    x_time.append(next(index))
    y_values.append(len(ind_list)) 
    
    im[0].set_array(MATR1)
    im[1].set_array(MATR2)
    im[2].set_array(MATR3)
    im[4].set_data(x_time, y_erbpopulation) # ERROR FROM HERE

    return im

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=NUMDAYS-1, interval=10, blit=True, repeat=False)
```

---

Updated question:

After making some of the suggested changes, my animation is still not showing. See my updated code below.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, num=None, figsize=(16, 12), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

MATR1 = np.zeros((100, 100))
MATR2 = np.zeros((100, 100))
MATR3 = np.zeros((100, 100))

# Coordinates lists for the line plot
x_time = []
y_values = []


im = list()
im.append(ax[0][0].imshow(MATR1, cmap='Reds', animated=True))
im.append(ax[0][1].imshow(MATR2, cmap='Greens', animated=True))
im.append(ax[1][0].imshow(MATR3, animated=True))
im.append(ax[1][1].plot(x_time, y_values, animated=True)[0])

def animate(i):
    ax[1][1].cla()
    
    # Here a lot of code that determines the values that are inserted into the matrices and the value
    # to add in the y_values coordinates list for the line, let's say now i+5 #
    
    x_time.append(i)
    y_values.append(i+5) 
    
    im[0].set_array(MATR1)
    im[1].set_array(MATR2)
    im[2].set_array(MATR3)
    im[4].set_data(x_time, y_values)

    return im

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=100, interval=10, blit=True, repeat=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [matplotlib plotting documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html) you'll see that `ax.plot` returns a list of `Line2D` objects. In this case, that list contains just a single object. But, you're appending the list to `im` when you only want the `Line2D` object. So, you simply need to index the first value of the return as so:

```py
im.append(ax[1][1].plot(x_time, y_values, animated=True)[0])
```

---

Updated solution:

1. The use of `animated=True` is not what you think, it's for manually created animations with blotting (see [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/blitting.html)). So, those should be removed.
2. You don't need `ax[1,1].cla()`. Using `set_data` will handle the update.
3. You need to set the axes limits because the default will be out of range (matplotlib doesn't know the extent when you made the plot).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np

plt.close("all")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(16, 12),)

MATR1 = np.random.random((100, 100))
MATR2 = np.random.random((100, 100))
MATR3 = np.random.random((100, 100))

x_time = []
y_values = []


im = []
im.append(ax[0][0].imshow(MATR1, cmap='Reds'))
im.append(ax[0][1].imshow(MATR2, cmap='Greens'))
im.append(ax[1][0].imshow(MATR3))
im.append(ax[1][1].plot(x_time, y_values)[0])

ax[1,1].set_xlim(0, 100)
ax[1,1].set_ylim(5, 105)

def animate(i):    
    x_time.append(i)
    y_values.append(i+5) 
    
    im[0].set_array(MATR1)
    im[1].set_array(MATR2)
    im[2].set_array(MATR3)
    im[3].set_data(x_time, y_values)

    return im

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=100, interval=10, blit=True, repeat=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because the set_data() method is not supported for lists. You need to create a Line2D object instead of a list in order to be able to use the set_data() method.

This should work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# Initialize the matrices and the line plot
MATR1 = np.zeros((100, 100))
MATR2 = np.zeros((100, 100))
MATR3 = np.zeros((100, 100))
x_time = []
y_values = []

# Create the subplots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
im1 = ax[0, 0].imshow(MATR1, cmap='Reds', animated=True)
im2 = ax[0, 1].imshow(MATR2, cmap='Greens', animated=True)
im3 = ax[1, 0].imshow(MATR3, animated=True)
line = ax[1, 1].plot([], [], animated=True)

# Create the animation
def animate(i):
    ax[1, 1].cla()
    x_time.append(i)
    y_values.append(i * i)
    im1.set_array(MATR1)
    im2.set_array(MATR2)
    im3.set_array(MATR3)
    line.set_data(x_time, y_values)
    return im1, im2, im3, line

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=100, interval=100)
plt.show()
```